# roslaunch ocl deployer node does not recognize '-s foo.ops --'

Tags: ros, roslaunch, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run:

rosrun ocl deployer-gnulinux -s foo.ops

This works just fine, however when I try this from within a *.launch file

(documented here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ocl)

I get:

Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option -s

It looks like the arguments are being treated differently when called this way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11759/roslaunch-ocl-deployer-node-does-not-recognize-%27-s-foo.ops---%27/) by [brianw1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1300/brianw1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Brian,

you are definitively using the correct syntax. All I can think of is something goes wrong with combining it with the gnome-terminal command. I'm using very similar syntax, but with the x-terminal instead, so maybe you could try that one and see if that gives you any better results:

< node name="orocos" pkg="ocl" type="deployer-gnulinux" launch-prefix="xterm -e" args="-s $(find orocos)/system.ops --     ">

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0